# Windows 10 abuse me with broken upgrades everytime

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I upgraded to Windows 10 which was previously windows 7, it is now unsupported for my laptop. 
Now it keeps telling me to restart for upgrades everytime I use it. And when I do, it can never install them and does a rollback on these recent upgrades. And it never stops, I just want to rip off the upgrade feature leave me alone with half broken OS. I don't even have firewall turned on.

Comment: How is this "unclear what you're asking"? At the moment it has two close votes for that reason. It's pretty obvious what s/he's trying to achieve.

Comment: You haven't given us much information yet. Please edit your question and include specific details, symptoms, and error messages, so that we can diagnose the cause and solution of the issues you are experiencing.

Comment: @Frank I was not (yet) one of those close votes, but his question is "aaaugh, it's broke and I'm frustrated!!!" We need clear descriptions of the symptoms, specific error messages if there are any, and any other possibly relevant information. There are simply too many possible causes for failed updates/upgrades (which is which?), and firewalls being off or on are not likely to be in any way related.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or **add additional details to highlight exactly what you need**. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

This happens to many people, it is usually drivers that are not compatible with your hardware configuration, BUT to solve this the easier way (may be the fastest also), download a [full installation of windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), using that tool and install it as an update, you will not lose any installed program, your updates will finally work, and that painful message and waiting will stop., it will take you about an hour to install it.

Comment: I would like to point out that 1607 which is indeed the last version specific hardware will receive, is a long-term support branch version, my point is of course that the reason the upgrade to a newer feature update is failing can likely be solved so the upgrade can happen.  The hardware that can only use 1607 will NOT be prompted to upgrade to 1703.

Comment: 5 out of 98 PCs here at work (all the same model) failed some updates, with exactly the same symptoms, it is really common, all the others did it fine, so i had to update to the latest from the iso, no problems after that.